# Red lines on screen when I boot

Tags: windows

Issue I'm getting when I boot up it is skipping the ASUS logo and ability to F2 into BIOS and just shows these red lines. Sometimes it will load into Windows automatic repair but none of the options in there seem to help. It happened while playing a new game the screen flickered when trying to load into a new map which is GFX intensive because of the amount of fog in the map. Both screens then went black and one pixelated. I think it could be the AMD drivers? I've unplugged and checked the connections on the GPU and cleaned the PCI-E port but this did not help. I'm currently searching online but don't know too much about this and don't want to break it.

[image]

Comment: Loaded into Safe mode: https://imgur.com/a/dlEWk Any ideas?

Comment: There are two things you should try. Reinstalling the AMD drivers in safe mode, and trying a different PCI-e slot. I would personally try the PCI-e slot first. If the same problem happens, then try removing and reinstalling the drivers. You're successfully booting into safe mode because Windows is using a standard VGA driver that is supported by all graphics cards, instead of the AMD drivers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try re-installing your drivers from your graphics cards official
   website
2. Try with another graphics card.

If none of the above works, you might have some issues with your motherboard.

If you still have questions comment here.

Comment: So any feedback?